Use extended controls on physical device
In Android Studio, there is extended controls on the Android Emulator to send data, change device properties, control apps, and more. I want to use extended controls on my physical device. For example, I want to make the battery status always shown as 12%, even when it is not actually 12%. Is it possible?

This is really a development question so I am going to vote to close this question as off-topic, but the answer is you don't... Extended Controls are only for emulators that do not have those physical components, not physical devices and battery information is now protected system information, even to gather extended battery stats special permissions in adb are required (like with GSAM) to just read privileged system information.

@acejavelin I could see this as an end-user question since the underlying question is not about development per se, but "how to achieve what extended controls do on real device", though, since extended controls have many, I wonder how specific the answer should be, e.g. just a simple "no, it's not possible" because it's only for emulators, or including a workaround for each control, e.g. need root and blabla.

The extended controls allow to change the emulator settings. Physical devices have fixed settings or values like battery status which bases on sensors and physical values. Therefore what you want is mostly not possible, other may be possible using adb commands.
